# I am getting a ClassCastException, but my source type object is of supertype and cast operator is of subtype

Tags: java

When I am executing the code below, why am I getting a ClassCastException?

```
class Test extends Test3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test3 t3 = new Test3();
        Test t = (Test) t3;
        System.out.print("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because a `Test3` isn't a `Test`: a `Test` is a `Test3`. Same way that a `Mammal` isn't a `Dog`, but a `Dog` is a `Mammal`.

Comment: That's exactly what you can't do.  You can't cast an object to something it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is done this way with primitive data types .But if you try with a String for example which is a [class] you cant do that without methods like `int Stringvariable = Integer.parseInt(Stringvariable)` to convert from String to Integer or `String intvariable = String.valueof(intvariable)`to convert from Integer to String.

`parseInt(Stringvariable)` is a method in Integer class.
`valueof(intvariable)` is a method in String class .If you want to establish any casting relation do it via methods.